# On the proof that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac {a^k}{(1+a^k x) (1+ a^{k+1}x)}=\frac 1 {1-a} \left( \frac 1 {1+x} -\frac {a^n}{ 1+a^n x }\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

**Question:-**

Find the sum to $n$ terms of the following series

$$\frac{1}{(1+x) (1+ax)} + \frac{a}{(1+ax) (1+a^2 x)} + \frac{a^2}{(1+a^2 x) (1+a^3 x)} + \cdots$$

---

**My solution:-**

First of all I found out the general term of the series

$$t_n=\frac {a^n}{(1+a^n x) (1+ a^{n+1}x)} $$

Now to find out the partial fraction, I multiplied and divided the $t_n$ by $(a-1) x$. The partial fraction of the $t_n$ looks like this

$$t_n =\frac {a^n (a-1) x }{(( a-1) x) [ (1+a^n x) (1+ a^{n+1} x)] } =\frac{( 1+ a^{n+1} x ) -( 1+ a^n x )}{((a-1)x) [(1+ a^n x) (1+ a^{n+1}x)]} =\frac 1 {(a-1) x} \left(\frac{1}{1+ a^n x} -\frac {1}{1+a^{n+1} x}\right) $$

As, $n \ge 0$,son on summing till all the $n$ terms the diagonal terms start to cancel out and we are left with

$$ S_n=\sum_{n=0}^{n-1} t_n = \sum_{n=0}^{n-1}{ \frac 1 {(a-1) x } \left( \frac 1 { 1+ a^n x } -\frac 1 { 1+ a^{n+1} x }  \right)  } = \left( \frac 1 {(a-1) x }  \right) \left( \frac 1 {1+x} -\frac 1 { 1+a^n x}  \right) $$

---

**The answer given in the book:-**

$$\left( \frac 1 {1-a}  \right) \left( \frac  1 {1+x} -\frac {a^n}{ 1+a^n x }\right)$$

Now, where did the $x$ in the $\dfrac{1}{(a-1)x}$ go and from where did the $a^{n}$ come in $\displaystyle \dfrac { { a }^{ n } }{ 1+{ a }^{ n }x }$

Comment: Have you checked whether the two expressions are actually the same or not?

Comment: They are actually the same.

Comment: Yeah, now that i see they are indeed the same.

Comment: What about trying $x=0$ or $a=0$ in your computations ?

Comment: @Thomas:- Hmm...according to what you pointed out the answer that the book has given can accept the value of $x=0$ but answer that i have arrived at did not, but both of these answers can accept the value $a=0$ and also give the expression that is expected. But I did not get your point as to what you are concluding as after simplification the expression of their sums does come out the same.

Comment: @user350331 to continue Thomas's point, are the functions $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ and $g(x)=1$ truly "*the same*"?  $g(x)$ does not have any poles, but $f(x)$ has a pole at $x=0$ (*although it is a "removable singularity" it is still a pole*).  Is then the expression you got truly "the same" as the expression the book gives?  Although they may agree at every number where there is not a singularity, do they agree when $x=0$?

Comment: The error occurred when you said "*I multiplied and divided the $t_n$ by $(a-1)x$*" You cannot multiply and divide by zero, so care needs to be taken if the variable you multiply and divide by can take the value of zero.  As for algebraically manipulating to go from one expression to the other, note that $\frac{a}{a+b} = \frac{a+0}{a+b}=\frac{a+b-b}{a+b}=\frac{a+b}{a+b}-\frac{b}{a+b}=1-\frac{b}{a+b}$.  Use this trick for both fractions, and distribute the $\frac{1}{x}$ appropriately.

Comment: @JMoravitz:- So, my answer is an incomplete one as it does not accept the value $x=0$ and the book's answer does but, then when I simplify the expression I get the same expression which I would have got when I would have simplified the the expression the book provided. Now, what I did was work backwards on the answer that I got after simplification of the expression, the way that i arrived at it when i was simplifying the book's expression, to put it simply reach from my answer to the book's given answer.(Part 1/2)

Comment: @JMoravitz During this process I see that I had to cancel $x$ from the numerator and denominator, which means that in the book's answer too we can't accept $x=0$. Part(2/2)

Comment: Can someone clarify how these two expressions are the same ?

Comment: @user230452 $$\frac{1}{1+ x} -\frac {1}{1+a^{n} x}=\left(1-\frac{x}{1+ x}\right) -\left(1-\frac {a^nx}{1+a^{n} x}\right)=x\left(\frac{a^n}{1+ a^n x} -\frac {1}{1+ x}\right)$$

Comment: @Did That's pretty brilliant !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the general term is $$t_j=\frac{a^j}{(1+a^jx)(1+a^{n+1}x)} \ ,\qquad  j=0,1,2,\dots,$$
we can decompose it into partial fractions as follows (so as to using finite telescoping  series). Suppose $$t_j=\frac{a^j}{(1+a^jx)(1+a^{n+1}x)}=\frac{A}{1+a^jx}+\frac{B}{1+a^{n+1}x},$$
then $$A=\frac{a^j}{1-a^{j+1}\cdot\frac{1}{a^j}}=\frac{a^j}{1-a}, \quad B=\frac{a^j}{1-a^j\cdot \frac{1}{a^{j+1}}}=\frac{a^{j+1}}{a-1},$$
and so
\begin{gather*}
t_j=\frac{1}{1-a}\left(\frac{a^j}{1+a^jx}-\frac{a^{j+1}}{1+a^{j+1}x}\right).
\end{gather*}
Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}t_j=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{1-a}\left(\frac{a^j}{1+a^jx}-\frac{a^{j+1}}{1+a^{j+1}x}\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{1-a}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{a^j}{1+a^jx}-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{a^{j+1}}{1+a^{j+1}x}\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{1-a}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{a^j}{1+a^jx}-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{a^{j}}{1+a^{j}x}\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{1-a}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{a^j}{1+a^jx}-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{a^j}{1+a^jx}-\frac{a^{n}}{1+a^nx}\right)\\
=&\frac{1}{1-a}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{a^{n}}{1+a^nx}\right).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Your result is the same as the answer from the book. Proof below :

$$f(a,x)=\left( \frac 1 {1-a}  \right) \left( \frac  1 {1+x} -\frac {a^n}{ 1+a^n x }\right)$$
$$f(a,x)=\left( \frac 1 {(1-a)x}  \right) \left( \frac  x {1+x} -\frac {a^n x}{ 1+a^n x }\right)$$
$\frac  x {1+x}=1-\frac  1 {1+x}$

$\frac {a^n x}{ 1+a^n x } = 1-\frac {1}{ 1+a^n x }$

$$f(a,x)=\left( \frac 1 {(1-a)x}  \right) \left( \left(1-\frac  1 {1+x}\right) -\left(1-\frac {1}{ 1+a^n x }\right) \right)$$
$$f(a,x)=\left( \frac 1 {(1-a)x}  \right)  \left(-\frac  1 {1+x} +\frac {1}{ 1+a^n x } \right) = \left( \frac 1 {(a-1)x}  \right)  \left(\frac  1 {1+x} -\frac {1}{ 1+a^n x } \right)$$
$$\left( \frac 1 {1-a}  \right) \left( \frac  1 {1+x} -\frac {a^n}{ 1+a^n x }\right)=\left( \frac 1 {(a-1)x}  \right)  \left(\frac  1 {1+x} -\frac {1}{ 1+a^n x } \right)$$

Remark :

$\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}$ is a bad notation because $n$ is a constant, not a variable. Better use two different symbols.

COMMENT :

Sorry, I just see the answer of Did in the comment section. It's the same proof as mine but more concise and earlier.